# Confusing (but probably easy) question regarding boundedness

Tags: real-analysis

Is $x^2$ bounded on $(-\infty,+\infty)$? Seeing as $x$ never reaches $\infty$ can I say that |$x^2$|$\leq M$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: A function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ can never "reach" infinity in the sense that for some $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $f(x) = \infty$ because $\infty \notin \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unbounded. For given $M > 0$, choosing $x = \sqrt{2M}$ makes $|x^2| > M$.

Answer (score 2):

To prove the function $x^2$ is bounded, you have to produce a number $M$ with $|x^2| \le M$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  You can't just write $|x^2| \le M$ without saying what $M$ is.

Is it true for $M=1$?  Is it true that $|x^2| \le 1$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$?  Or is there an $x$ with $|x^2| > 1$?

Is it true for $M=2$?

Is it true for $M=3$?

Can you see why it can't be true for *any* $M$?